# I want transmit and receive data through a single UART using two different times

Tags: timer, serial-port, uart, microchip, dspic

I want to transmit and receive data through a single UART using timers for 10ms and 1ms. IF 1ms timer flag is set then 10ms transmission should halt and other should start because 1ms transmission is urgent. After completing this the first should resume. How to do it in dspic33ep microcontroller series?

**Note**: Uart availability is limited by application.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a single timer interrupt triggering at 1kHz (i.e. every ms). The interrupt would set a pair of global semaphore flag indicating (a) that a transmission is required, and (b) what type of transmission should occur. The semaphores should be declared volatile.

Then, your main control loop can examine/poll the semaphores to determine whether it is time to make a transmission, and what transmission type is desired. Take care to examine each semaphore only once as their value can change between two tests. Your control loop also needs to reset the time-to-send-data semaphore.

This method will have some latency (timing between the interrupt setting the semaphore, and the loop testing the semaphores).

There is also the issue of the speed of transmission. You are going to have to use a rather high baud rate to get any decent amount of data transmitted at a repeat rate of 1kHz. For example, at 9600 baud, it takes about 1ms to transmit just one character.